# select does not wait for timeout value in c++ sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

I've wrote a server code which accepts new clients and data from the clients. But the problem is that select does not wait until the timeout though there are no data coming from the clients. I want to wait for 5 seconds and send heart beats for available clients. But it wait 5 seconds in the first iteration and then send heartbeats rapidly in next iterations. How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
void * Communicate(void * id)
{
int *iSockID = (int *) id;
int listener =  *iSockID;

fd_set master;    // master file descriptor list
fd_set read_fds;  // temp file descriptor list for select() read
fd_set write_fds; // temp file descriptor list for select() read
int fdmax;        // maximum file descriptor number

int i, j, rv;

FD_ZERO(&master);    // clear the master and temp sets
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
// add the listener to the master set
FD_SET(listener, &master);
printf("Listener is %d \n" , listener);

// keep track of the biggest file descriptor
fdmax = listener; // so far, it's this one
//accept 3 clients


// main loop
for(;;) {
    read_fds = master; // copy it
    write_fds = master;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    int iResult = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, &tv) ;
    if (iResult == -1) 
    {
        perror("select");
        exit(4);
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) 
    {           
        //send work for clients
        SendHeartBeats(write_fds , fdmax , listener , i );

    }

    // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
    // ADD NEW CONNECTIONS READ FROM CONNECTIONS    
    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)
    {   


        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) 
        { // we got one!!
            // handle new connections               
            if (i == listener) 
            {                                    
                AcceptNewClients(master , fdmax , listener );   
            } else 
            {
                AccepeDataFromClients(i , master);
            } // END handle data from client
        } // END got new incoming connection
    } // END looping through file descriptors
    sleep(3);
} // END for(;;)
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot provide a more detailed answer without seeing the implementation of `SendHeartBeats`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated in a comment you are using `Linux 2.6.27`. Since in Linux, an `fd_set` is a structure containing an integral type array, using assignment to copy `master` to `read_fds` is fine.

The reason why your `select` call is not blocking is because you are initializing both `read_fds` and `write_fds` from `master`. Your idle client sockets are always going to be writeable, so you wake up immediately. As an aside, selecting for writeable on your `listener` socket is pointless.

You should only set the client socket in the `write_fds` when you attempt to write but get the `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fd_set variables by equals.  You need to use FD_COPY.  If you don't, you just copy a handle to the actual data, which is already marked as finished.

Comment: +1.  `fdmax = listener;` is just waiting to fail too, especially given the awkward need for `AcceptNewClients(master , fdmax , listener );` to update `fdmax`.  And, the code shouldn't do a `sleep(3)` - let the timeout handle that, doing a post-timeout elapsed-time check to avoid excessively frequent heartbeats if you care.

Comment: I've included the sys/time.h file. but FD_COPY gives me the error FD_COPY was not declared in this scope. @Tony I've used the sleep() since the timeout didn't work. con you tell me what I'm doing wrong here??..

Comment: @Zeus: the timeout won't work if you don't reconstruct your fd sets and provide the right max... as soon as anything gets set it'll stay set.  For FD_COPY - did you check your man page or other system documentation?  stys/time.h is definitely right on some systems (e.g. some IBMs) - but these things can vary, or it might not be available at all.  You can potentially reset/clear it and set the flags again, or on some systems you don't need to use FD_COPY - check for example how GNU libc does it at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html

Comment: @TonyD uname -r gave me "Linux  2.6.27.19-5-default" version. I have included the sys/time.h. But still the compiler complaining that it cant identify the FD_COPY.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code to re-initialize the `read_fd` and `write_fd` variables each time `select()` is called, as it modifies them upon exit so you need to reset them each time.  As others said, using the `=` operator to copy the `master` variable is not the correct way to copy an `fd_set` struct.

Try this:

```
void * Communicate(void * id)
{
    int *iSockID = (int *) id;
    int listener =  *iSockID;

    fd_set master;    // master file descriptor list
    fd_set read_fds;  // temp file descriptor list for select() read
    fd_set write_fds; // temp file descriptor list for select() read
    struct timeval tv;
    int fdmax;        // maximum file descriptor number
    int i, j, rv;

    printf("Listener is %d \n", listener);

    // add the listener to the master set
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_SET(listener, &master);

    // keep track of the biggest file descriptor
    fdmax = listener; // so far, it's this one
    //accept 3 clients

    // main loop
    clock_t c1 = clock();
    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);

        #ifdef MSWINDOWS
        // Windows does not have FD_COPY()
        for (u_int i = 0; i < master.fd_count; ++i)
        {
            FD_SET(master.fd_array[i], &read_fd);
            FD_SET(master.fd_array[i], &write_fd);
        }
        #else
        FD_COPY(&master, &read_fd);
        FD_COPY(&master, &write_fd);
        #endif

        tv.tv_sec = 1;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        int iResult = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, &tv);
        if (iResult == -1) 
        {
            perror("select");
            exit(4);
        }

        clock_t c2 = clock();
        if (((c2-c1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 5)
        {
            c1 = c2;
            for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) 
            {           
                if ((i != listener) && FD_ISSET(i, &write_fds))
                { 
                    //send work for client
                    SendHeartBeat(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
        // ADD NEW CONNECTIONS READ FROM CONNECTIONS    
        for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)
        {   
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) 
            {
                // we got one!!
                if (i == listener) 
                {                                    
                    AcceptNewClient(master, fdmax, listener);   
                }
                else 
                {
                    AcceptDataFromClient(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Problem is that there is a compile error.. " FD_COPY was not declared in this scope".

Comment: If the socket API for your compiler does not have `FD_COPY()` available (and not all platforms do), then you will have to loop throuh the `master` list manually, like I showed for Windows.